# Magento configuration cache not working with multistore

Tags: php, magento, caching

I am using the multistore feature in magento. To speed it up I have enabled the cache. Problem occurs with multiple stores when configuration cache is enabled. If I enable all caching except configuration (System(config.xml, local.xml) and modules configuration files(config.xml)), Multiple stores works but not with speed increased.

Following are more details:
When configuration cache is enabled with other cache options (everything previously cached flushed): I login into admin section of any one magento store and then logout from it. Now when I open admin section of another magento store (url of which is different) and login into new store, it redirects back to previously opened magento store admin URL. Same happens with front end. When a magento store front end is opened it works fine and it is cached. Now when I try to open another store front end it takes me to the first store that was opened. I think it is not allowing to change base URL when new store is opened.

Example(Steps to reproduce):

1. Login to first magento store admin, let's say http://www.example1.com/admin
2. Then logout from this store admin.
3. Open another magento store admin and login, for ex. http://www.example2.com/admin
4. After submitting login form it redirects back to http://www.example1.com/admin and login session starts with this URL instead of http://www.example2.com/admin

Can anyone please help me out how to make caching worked well in multistore magento website. I have 180 magento stores out of which 8 are being used currently.